# Passing slots through from Parent to Child Components

Tags: vue.js

I have built a user-defined component (`async-select`) on top of another component ([vue mutliselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)) like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/2x7n4rL6/4/

Since the original vue-multiselect component offers a couple of slots, I don't want to loose the chance to use them. So my goal is to make these slots available from inside my custom component. In other words, I want to something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/2x7n4rL6/3/

But that code oes not work.
However, if I add the slot to the child component itself, it works just fine (which you can see from the fact that options become red-colored).

https://jsfiddle.net/2x7n4rL6/1/

After surfing the web, I have come across [this article](https://gist.github.com/loilo/73c55ed04917ecf5d682ec70a2a1b8e2), but it does not seem to work
Is there any way in VueJS to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slots can be confusing!

First, you need a `template` element to define the slot content:

```
  <async-select :value="value" :options="options">
    <template v-slot:option-tmpl="{ props }">
      <div class="ui grid">
        <div style="color: red">{{ props.option.name }}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </async-select>
```

Then, in the parent component, you need a `slot` element. That `slot` element itself can be inside of another `template` element, so its contents can be put in a slot of its own parent.

```
<multiselect
    label="name"
    ref="multiselect"
    v-model="localValue"
    placeholder="My component"
    :options="options"
    :multiple="false"
    :taggable="false">
        <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
            <slot name="option-tmpl" :props="props"></slot>
        </template>
</multiselect>
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/ph0s1jda/